# 1 I am doing the cs50 course and decided to run the code from there on my MacBook

Tags: c, cs50

I have the following code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x = get_int("whats x? ");
    int y = get_int("whats y? ");

    if (x < y)
    {
        printf("x is less than y\n");
    }
}
```

It keeps giving me this error

```
moutarrjallow@Moutarrs-MBP cclang % make ccompare
cc     ccompare.c   -o ccompare
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_get_int", referenced from:
      _main in ccompare-91f0e5.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [ccompare] Error 1
```

Comment: Did you install the [CS50 library](https://cs50.readthedocs.io/libraries/cs50/c/) on your MacBook? Are you linking with the command-line option `-lcs50`, as stated in the instructions?

Comment: where do i link it with the command line option

Comment: I believe if you set the environment variables as described in the link I posted, then `make` will automatically add it for you. You will have to edit your `.bashrc` file if you are using bash. I don't know if this will work with other shells. Also, I don't know what shell is normally used on Macintosh computers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [link](https://cs50.readthedocs.io/libraries/cs50/c/) with the cs50 library by adding the `-lcs50` to above.  In your Makefile you can probably do that by setting `LDLIBS := -lcs50`.

Comment: How do i link it, where do I add -lcs50, I have a makefile with the commands LDLIBS += -lcs50
CC := clang saved in the same directory as cs50.h and ccompare.c

Comment: The above was my best guess without seeing your makefile.  If you have LDLIBS then it just link the file when you build your program after the next change.